# How to run command-line process in karma

Tags: angularjs, integration-testing, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I am writing an integration test (not a unit test) for my AngularJS / CouchDB application using Karma. I realize that in unit tests mocking the database is important. I am deliberately NOT mocking the database since this is an integration test. I explicitly DO want to interact with the database. I also do NOT want to use protractor for these integration tests. The motivation for these integration tests is to move tests that don't necessarily rely on the UI away from protractor to increase the overall speed of our tests.

The following works when I run code in protractor `exec("my command that loads data into the database")`.

In karma `exec()` is not available. How would you run a shell command in karma? Given how karma works, is this even possible?

If karma is not the best way to run integration tests, what would you recommend that I do?

Perhaps there is some way to run the shell command while karma is starting up?

Comment: You can run anything before karma in node, but karma is not supposed to be used for top-level tests, tools like protractor are.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov, thanks. I do use protractor but it is too slow for use in integration tests that don't need to interact with the UI.

If you want to supply an answer for how to "run anything before karma in node" I would appreciate it.